# How to have unity inspector variables modify each other bidirectionally and update in real time

Tags: unity, unity-ui

Trying to make some inspector controls that both modify the same thing but in different ways, and I want them to both update when the other is edited. Won't bore with the details but there's a reason. Boils down to:

float_1 with range 0-1
float_2 with user defined min / max

a mapping function that translates between the two, so `float_1=0` will become `float_2 min`, and 'float_1=1' will become `float_2 max`, and the reverse will happen if float 2 is modified.

I can do it in the Unity UI using getter / setters in properties, since I can know which setter is being called and can have it modify the other variable, ie:

```
    public float min;
    public float max;
    
    private float float_1;
    private float float_2;

    public float Float_1
    {
        get => float_1;

        set
        {
            float_1 = value;
            float_2 = Utl.Map(value, 0f, 1f, min, max);
        }
    }

    public float Float_2
    {
        get => float_2;

        set
        {
            float_2 = value;
            float_1 = Utl.Map(value, min, max, 0f, 1f);
        }
    }
```

However in the inspector I don't know which variable is being modified so I can't separate it out, and so I can only have a one-directional relationship.

If relevant, I also want this to work in the game isn't running, using OnValidate()

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a message called `OnValidate`:  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html

It checks to see if anything in the inspector has been edited.  So your new code would look something like this:

```
public float min;
public float max;

private float float_1;
private float float_2;

public float Float_1
{
    get => float_1;

    set
    {
        float_1 = value;
        float_2 = Utl.Map(value, 0f, 1f, min, max);
    }
}

public float Float_2
{
    get => float_2;

    set
    {
        float_2 = value;
        float_1 = Utl.Map(value, min, max, 0f, 1f);
    }
}

private void OnValidate()
{
    float_1 = Utl.Map(float_2, min, max, 0f, 1f);
    float_2 = Utl.Map(float_1, 0f, 1f, min, max);
}
```

(I didn't check to make sure the logic here works - just showing you `OnValidate`.  So make sure this doesn't break anything.)

---

But since you only want to run code on the changed value, you can check to see if it has been changed.  This feels rather dirty, but should work.  It is probably worth taking a step back and seeing if your architecture has some potential improvements though.

```
public float min;
public float max;

private float float_1;
private float float_2;
private float previous_float_1;
private float previous_float_2;

private void Awake()
{
    previous_float_1 = float_1;
    previous_float_2 = float_2;
}

public float Float_1
{
    get => float_1;

    set
    {
        float_1 = value;
        float_2 = Utl.Map(value, 0f, 1f, min, max);
    }
}

public float Float_2
{
    get => float_2;

    set
    {
        float_2 = value;
        float_1 = Utl.Map(value, min, max, 0f, 1f);
    }
}

private void OnValidate()
{
    if(float_1 != previous_float_1)
    {
        float_1 = Utl.Map(float_2, min, max, 0f, 1f);
        previous_float_1 = float_1;
    }
    if(float_2 != previous_float_2)
    {
        float_2 = Utl.Map(float_1, min, max, 0f, 1f);
        previous_float_2 = float_2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, already using OnValidate(), but that's my problem. It just tells me something has been changed but not what, so it tries to set both variables at once which also set each other, so it doesn't work

Comment: @arcadeperfect Ah, gotcha.  Updated answer.

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61524329/how-do-i-trace-the-source-of-the-call-onvalidate

Comment: @Evorlor I just spent minutes to craft my answer, and only to discover you foreran me, we even wrote the same code :P

Comment: Sometimes that's a good sign. Convergent evolution like that suggests it was probably a good solution! 

Comment: Thanks folks, if it works it works!

Answer (score 0):

Just as you hinted, [OnValidate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) is where you need to do some variable checking.

If you want to update `float_1` and `float_2` mutually when the user changes one's value, you can check it in this editor-only function:

```
public class Demo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float min;
    public float max;

    public float Float_1;
    public float Float_2;
    
    float float_1;
    float float_2;

    void OnValidate()
    {
        Float_1 = Mathf.Clamp(Float_1, 0, 1);
        Float_2 = Mathf.Clamp(Float_2, min, max);

        if (float_1 != Float_1)
        {
            float_1 = Float_1;
            float_2 = Mathf.Lerp(min, max, float_1);
            Float_2 = float_2;
        }
        else
        {
            float_2 = Float_2;
            float_1 = Mathf.InverseLerp(min, max, float_2);
            Float_1 = float_1;
        }
    }
}
```